# How to maintain property access with intellisense in an indexed type

Tags: typescript

Lets say I have an interface 'IndexedInterface' which should only have the description to hold properties of another interface type 'PropertyInterface'.

I use this to define an object with the interface 'IndexInterface' type. This works well, as the code completion will provide me with the information the 'PropertyInterface' for every property I add.

So far no problems.

But now I want to access a property from this object and the typescript compiler can't resolve the property names defined before.

Now the question: is there currently a way in typescript to achieve a combination of an indexed type with an derived type from an object declaration?

Thanks in advance.

```
interface PropertyInterface 
   someProp: string;
}

interface IndexedInterface {
  [key: string]: PropertyInterface;
}

const testObj: IndexedInterface = {
 prop1: {
   someProp: 'test'
 }
};

testObj. // here the intellisense should tell me that 'prop1' is available
```

Edit:

Thanks to Titian Cernicova-Dragomir, I found a dynamic way using a class:

```
class TypeMerger<T> {
    mergeTypes<U>(o: T): T & U {
        return o as T & U;
    }
}

const testObj = new TypeMerger<IndexedInterface>.mergeTypes({
 prop1: {
   someProp: 'test'
 }
});

testObj.prop1 // works like a charm now from intellisense
```

Also is has the advantage to have the properties from both classes available, if there is more in the indexed type.

Thank you for you answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only do this if you don't mind an extra function call. Variables can't at the same time be constrained to an interface but have the compiler infer the actual type of the object literal.

You can do it with a function that has a generic type parameter that is constrained but that will be inferred based on the actual parameter passed in :

```
interface PropertyInterface {
  someProp: string;
}


interface IndexedInterface {
  [key: string]: PropertyInterface;
}

function createIndexedInterface<T extends IndexedInterface>(o: T) {
  return o;
}

const testObj = createIndexedInterface({
  prop1: {
    someProp: 'test'
  }
});

testObj.prop1.someProp // ok
```

You can create a more generic version of the function, using a function that returns a function (your class solution is also a good one, adding this one for completeness)

```
function createIndexedInterface<T>() {
  return function <U extends T>(o: U) {
    return o;
  }
}
const testObj = createIndexedInterface<IndexedInterface>()({
  prop1: {
    someProp: 'test'
  }
});

testObj.prop1.someProp // ok
```

Comment: I like you solution. It actually works :)

I am still trying to find out if I can do this in a more generic way, like giving the type to result in as generic parameter.

Comment: Have updated the main and found a even more generic way thank you very much :)

Comment: @Karamuto Sorry I was in a meeting, added my generic version as well, yours works just fine too. Good luck :)